# IntelliJ IDEA does not display run icon for @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am in the middle of setting up a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ idea.  I was reading about IntelliJ's [Spring Boot support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#access-http-request-mappings) and I'm supposed to be able to see a green run icon in the gutter of my `@RestController` next to my `@RequestMapping`.  The application is working fine and I can even see the mapping in the Run tab under Mappings.  I was wondering what I'm missing?

I've created a project using Spring Initializr to show the problem.  The issue is reproducible in the [DemoController](https://github.com/beedaan/Spring-Boot-Demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoController.java) and the project is available on [Github](https://github.com/beedaan/Spring-Boot-Demo)

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? Would it be possible to share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Thank you.

Comment: I think that the green arrow icon to run the request will only appear *when the application is running*.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've created a Github project that reproduces the issue.  I'm using IDEA Ultimate

Comment: @JosepOriolSoler That's a good thought.  The problem is happening when the application is running.  You can even hit the endpoint from the Run -> Mappings tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the [known IntelliJ IDEA bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216222) specific to Spring Boot 2.2.x versions.

Comment: Thank you!  Glad I'm not alone.  I also have the "Mapping Handler Method Not Found" message.