# How to enable globe icon right next to @PostMapping in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, testing, httpclient

I am using java 18 on intellij trying to learn SpringBoot. I see that we can run httpclient clicking on globe icon that can be seen right next to "@PostMapping", but I do NOT see it. WHY?? Why does "setting up"/configuration part annoys the hell out of software engineer? Please HELP ME

Comment: What IntelliJ version are you using? You can find it under Help > About. My first guess is that the globe only shows if you have the Spring plugin, which is an Ultimate (paid) feature not present in the Community (free) edition.

Comment: Also, see if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144213/intellij-idea-does-not-display-run-icon-for-requestmapping) addresses the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available in IntelliJ Enterprise version.

It gives 3 options 'Go to declaration or usage', 'Generate request in HTTP Client' & 'Show all endpoints of module'